# need to give animation to revolution slider instead of slides

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have wordpress site and i installed revolution slider in it.
site : http://secondplacecroatia.com/

Using 6 Slider in my home page..

Now , i want to animate each slider, repeating it i want to animate each slider.. Not individual slides...

Any one know ? how can i give fade in and slide up animation to each slider ???

Do i have simple solution with  jquery animate or other ??
$("").animate({}, "slow" );

Answer (score 0):

To be honest i can not really follow what you try to achieve here. You have 6 sliders added into 1 page, each slider has "x" slides.  Normally all slider start the slideshow and rotating the slides in unlimited loops.  Dont really understand which kind of "animation" do you try to add to the sliders ?

As best, contact us directly via our support center at http://themepunch.com/support-center and we help you as good we can !